# Develop using Bootstrap using css.map

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, less

I'm trying to develop using Bootstrap 3.3.7, and I downloaded all the starter files (not the source files).

It does have bootstrap.css and bootstrap.css.map, which I understand that .css.map file is a source map between the source files to the css file so I can use it to debug in browser.

But since I don't have the .less file or .scss/.sass file in the folder, when I'm trying to make change in CSS file, where do I edit it? Or shall I regenerate a .scss file using .css and .css.map file? I don't think edit in CSS directly would be a good idea right?

Comment: You can add another CSS file of your own and add all your CSS there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `custom.css` file and add `<link href="/path/to/custom.css">` to your header.